# Paypal Ipn Not Working Code Stops

Tags: php, paypal

My paypal ipn code stops working after the while or does not seem to be gathering the right information from the while or the information is not set. Does anybody have any ideas as to what should be the right input for this line of code. Here is the code:

```
 while (!feof($fp)) {
 $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
```

Is the code above functioning properly with the following code. Here is the code:

```
  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Here is most of the code:

```
// Response from Paypal

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// assign posted variables to local variables
$data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
$data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
$data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
$data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
$data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
$data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {    

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

Does anybody know why it does not pass this section of the paypal ipn code?

Comment: Should `ssl` be `https`? Also, in what way does this not work? Where does it stop?

Comment: $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use curl instead of ssl socket. You need build your request (in my example, $req), as pair-value string, ie: `$req="key1=value1&key2=value2"`;

```
  $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

  if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
      curl_close($ch);
      exit;
  }
  curl_close($ch);
```

And you will get Paypal result in `$res` var.

Answer (score 1):

I found this script:
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

I was having the same issue, with getting no response.  Decided to research using cURL instead.  This script works perfectly.  I did need to install cURL and download the cert referenced in the script comments.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
```

To this:

```
$value = urlencode($value);
```

You only need to use `stripslashes` there if you're runnning PHP with Magic Quotes on. As of PHP 5.4, that's (thankfully) no longer possible.

Paypal allows user data to contain backslashes (I have seen it in IPN data in the `address_street` variable). If you strip the backslashes out from IPN data that had them, Paypal will return an INVALID response.